# Border around li tag

Tags: html, css, border

Is there any way that the border in a li tag includes the number and not just the content?

Here is the jsfiddle of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Markinhos/VSnnd/8/

I want the border includes the number two.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Add `list-style-position:inside;`

```
.borderlist {
    list-style-position:inside;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

is the CSS attribute your looking for, it will treat the list number as if it is inside the CSS box model.

Answer (score 6):

you can do this by `list-style-position: inside;`

> The list-style-position CSS property specifies the position of the marker box in the principal block box. :[***MDN***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hEHrp/)